# How to get the common value by comparing two pyspark dataframes

Tags: pyspark

I am migrating the pandas dataframe to pyspark. I have two dataframes in pyspark with different counts. The below code I am able to achieve in pandas but not in pyspark. How to compare the 2 dataframes values in pyspark and put the value as new column in df2.

```
def impute_value (row,df_custom):
    for index,row_custom in df_custom.iterrows():
        if row_custom["Identifier"] == row["IDENTIFIER"]:
           row["NEW_VALUE"] = row_custom['CUSTOM_VALUE']
    return row["NEW_VALUE"]

df2['VALUE'] = df2.apply(lambda row: impute_value(row, df_custom),axis =1)
```

How can I convert this particular function to pyspark dataframe? In pyspark, I cannot pass the row wise value to the function(impute_value).

I tried the following.

```
df3= df2.join(df_custom, df2["IDENTIFIER"]=df_custom["Identifier"],"left")
df3.WithColumnRenamed("CUSTOM_VALUE","NEW_VALUE")
```

This is not giving me the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the left join itself should do the needful

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df3= df2.join(df_custom.withColumnRenamed('Identifier','Id'), df2["IDENTIFIER"]=df_custom["Id"],"left")

df3=df3.withColumn('NEW_VALUE',f.col('CUSTOM_VALUE')).drop('CUSTOM_VALUE','Id')
```

Comment: Instead of joining, can I just compare 2 dataframes with df2["IDENTIFIER"]==df_custom["Identifier"] condition only return df_custom["CUSTOM_VALUE"] ? If i join, am getting 2 columns added in df3 because of less counts in df_custom (Identifier and IDENTIFIER) which I don't wanted to do like this ...

Comment: you can drop the additional columns and you should be good. The compare you are trying to do is the crux of join. Also updated the answer for dropping additional columns

Comment: if we drop IDENTIFIER, df3.show() is not showing up Identifier column(df_custom) .. it just shows NEW_VALUE only ... but if we didn't drop IDENTIFIER, df3.show() shows both IDENTIFIER and Identifier as we joined